# Prove or refute transitivity property for $\square \neg A \lor \lozenge \lozenge A $

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I don't know how should I solve this problem in modal logic:

Does $$\square \neg A \lor \lozenge \lozenge A $$ satisfy transitivity ?

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

First, I assume that you are talking about normal modal logics.

Transitivity is not enough. Your model needs to be reflexive (try to prove your formula in **S4** using analytical tables or some calculus).

As for a counter model for your formula in **K4** (minimal transitive normal logic), here it is: $w_0\longrightarrow w_1$. Set $w_0\nvDash A$ and $w_1\vDash A$ and see that your formula doesn't hold in $w_0$.

Now, a converse question. Can $\Box\neg A\vee\diamond\diamond A$ hold in a non-transitive model (where $\neg\forall w_1,w_2,w_3(R(w_1,w_2)\wedge R(w_2,w_3)\Rightarrow R(w_1,w_3))$)?

Sure, it can, because it holds in any model, where $\Box\neg A$ or $\diamond\diamond A$ holds and they can of course be non-transitive.

Answer (score 0):

This axiom, rewritten equivalently as $\Diamond A\to\Diamond\Diamond A$, expresses the well-known property that the frame is $dense$, i.e., it satisfies the property: "between any two points $x$ and $z$ such that $xRz$, there exists a point $y$ such that $xRy$ and $yRz$."

Density has no relation to transitivity: you can easily build a transitive but not dense frame; a dense but not transitive frame; a transitive dense frame, e.g., $(\mathbb{Q},<)$; a frame that is neither transitive nor dense. So the answer to your question is: yes, since a dense frame does not have to be transitive.